# Opengraph: facebook share image wrong image after change image

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

I use [Opengraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/opengraph_meta) to define the facebook share image.

I upload image APPLE.jpg in my article.
The meta tag is

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/APPLE.jpg" />`

Then, I found I uploaded the wrong image.
I edit the article and removed the APPLE.jpg image.
I upload a new image BANANA.jpg

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/BANANA.jpg" />
```

While I share the article to facebook.
The image is still showing APPLE.jpg image.

How do I settle this?

Comment: As the caches age, FB Crawler will typically fetch the new image and the issue will fix itself. Can you confirm if you are still able to see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook keeps your image in cache. So if you have changed your image, but kept the same name, you have two solutions :

1. Use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and fecth new scrape information. If the image doesn't change, use the second solution.
2. Change the name of your image, and Facebook will cache the new image.